# Multiple aguements error when passing variable values to SQL in python

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have managed to stump myself whilst trying to pass the value of a variable assigned in python tkinter, to an SQL database I set up, this is the code I used:

```
        new_db, c = SetUpDataBase()
        FirstName = entry1.get()
        LastName =entry2.get()
        DoB =entry3.get()
        Gender =entry4.get()
        MobileNo =entry5.get()
        HomeNo =entry6.get()
        Email =entry7.get()
```

and then the execute statement:

```
       c.executescript('''INSERT INTO Patients (Last_Name, First_Name, Date_of_Birth, Gender,
                        Home_Phone_Number, Mobile_Phone_Number, Email) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ''',(LastName,FirstName,DoB,Gender,HomeNo,MobileNo,Email))
```

this resulted in the error message:

```
Home_Phone_Number, Mobile_Phone_Number, Email) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ''',(LastName,FirstName,DoB,Gender,HomeNo,MobileNo,Email))
```

TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

and ideas on how to get around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation for `executescript` you'll see it takes a single argument: the script to run. You're passing it two arguments: a script to run and a tuple. `executescript` does not take parameter substitution the way some other database methods do.

The solution is to use `execute` rather than `executescript`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will try that and see if it works!

Answer (score 0):

I'm with @Bryan Dakley, here an example, won't you want to put to count the number of the fields every time at all? ;)

```
args = (LastName,FirstName,DoB,Gender,HomeNo,MobileNo,Email)

sql = "INSERT INTO Patients VALUES(%s)"%(",".join("?"*len(args)))

c.execute(sql, args)
```